# Windows software to set Date Taken metadata based on the date stamp on the image

Tags: photography, ocr, metadata

I am in the process of scanning and archiving thousands of old family photos, and many of them have a date in one corner left by the original camera, like this:

[image]

Not all images have it and some do not contrast the background well, but it would save a tremendous amount of time if I could set the metadata of the image based on the date so that my hosting software (Photoprism at the moment) can display and sort according to date correctly.

I'm wondering if there is already a tool for this or if I need to try and write it myself. I would imagine it is not the most uncommon situation so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.